# The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List':
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: https://medium.com/@pmatatias/await-vs-then-in-flutter-28c2ce600cea

Comment: Please do not post screenshots but code only. Also, use `await` when calling an async function.

Comment: lib/screen/new_tasks.dart:47:46: Error: Unexpected token 'await'.
      String imgString= Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes()) ;
                                             ^^^^^
lib/screen/new_tasks.dart:47:61: Error: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
      String imgString= Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes()) ;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you .this is a solution         String imgString= Utility.base64String( File(imgFile!.path).readAsBytesSync()) ;

Comment: but i found this problem that th space is full how i solve it ????this is code exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=5; query: SELECT id, photoName FROM PhotosTable
E/flutter ( 2096): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=5) sql 'SELECT id, photoName FROM PhotosTable' args []

Answer (score 0):

imgFile!.readAsBytes return a future which can't be assign in that place unless you made the function an asynchronous function (By adding **async** after the params bracket **"() async"** and **await** before the imgFile!.readAsBytes .

So it would be like

```
functionName() async {
Srting imgString = Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes)

// The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: lib/screen/new_tasks.dart:47:46: Error: Unexpected token 'await'.
      String imgString= Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes()) ;
                                             ^^^^^
lib/screen/new_tasks.dart:47:61: Error: The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
      String imgString= Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes()) ;

Comment: Make sure that you added the async part and please provide me with your code .

Comment: pickImageFromGallery()async{
    ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((imgFile) {
      String imgString= Utility.base64String(await imgFile!.readAsBytes()) ;
      Photo photo=Photo(id: 0,photoName: imgString);
      dbHelper!.save(photo);
      refreshImages();

    });
  }

Comment: static String base64String(Uint8List data){
    return base64Encode(data);
}